# ajax no funciton due e.preventdefault error and no update DB

Tags: javascript, ajax

few days ago I change my PHP version from 5.4 to 5.5 due to some code needed for render QR code. And today i found error in this function:

```
$(function changeStav() {

            $("#selPismoSet<?php echo $id;?>").change(function() {
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                del_id = del_id.replace("selPismoSet","");
                var id = del_id;
                var val = $('#selPismoSet<?php echo $id;?> option:selected').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "actions.php?action=changeStav",
                    data: 'id=' + id+ '&stav=' + val,
                    success: function(data){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#content, #ok<?php echo $id;?>').html(data);
                        console.log();
                    }
                });

                return false;           
            });

        });
```

I got this error:
[image]

I dont know where is the problem. Its possible that error is due to change PHP version?

Comment: So you have error "e is not defined" and still you couldn't figure out the problem?

Comment: `e` is usually an JavaScript event object and has nothing to do with PHP, don't know what event do you want to prevent there? :)

Comment: The php version has nothing to do with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Isn't it a bit late running `preventDefault()` in the success method?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an argument in your function. `e` is not defined

```html
$(function changeStav() {

            $("#selPismoSet<?php echo $id;?>").change(function(e) {
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                del_id = del_id.replace("selPismoSet","");
                var id = del_id;
                var val = $('#selPismoSet<?php echo $id;?> option:selected').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "actions.php?action=changeStav",
                    data: 'id=' + id+ '&stav=' + val,
                    success: function(data){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#content, #ok<?php echo $id;?>').html(data);
                        console.log();
                    }
                });

                return false;           
            });

        });
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit late running `preventDefault()` in the success method?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i think so too. actually i dont know the reason why did op added a `preventDefault()` in his function.

Comment: @jerome @RiggsFolly - i dont know why but without e.preventDefault() `$('#content, #ok<?php echo $id;?>').html(data);` cant load the div #content